# Pass all values from one page to another with one click

Tags: c#, session, datalist

I have a datalist which is in Emailenquiries.aspx page, i want to get those datalist values which are modified, into another page named Enquirymaintenance.aspx. please help me..

Here is my code

Emailenquiries.aspx (I just summerised the values to three)

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataKeyField="PD_ID" OnItemCommand ="DataList1_OnItemCommand" DataSourceID="sdsEnquiries">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <h2>Enquiry details</h2>
                    <ul class="left patientInfo">
                        <li>
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <asp:Label ID="PD_TitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PD_Title") %>' />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>First Name</label>
                            <asp:Label ID="PD_FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PD_FirstName") %>' />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Last Name</label>
                            <asp:Label ID="PD_LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PD_LastName") %>' />
                        </li>
                        <li>
</ul>
</ItemTemplate>

 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Promote as Enquiry" CommandName ="PromoteAsEnquiry" OnClick="btnPromote_Click" CssClass="htmlbutton" />
```

Emailenquiries.aspx.cs

```
    protected void DataList1_OnItemCommand(Object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "PromoteAsEnquiry")
        {                
            DataListItem row = DataList1.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex];

            DropDownList ddlTitle = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("PD_TitleLabel");
            Label lblFirstName = (Label)row.FindControl("PD_FirstNameLabel");
            Label lblLastName = (Label)row.FindControl("PD_LastNameLabel");

            Session["title"] = ddlTitle.Text;
            Session["firstname"] = lblFirstName.Text;
            Session["lastname"] = lblLastName.Text;

            Response.Redirect("EnquiryMaintenance.aspx");            
        }


    }
```

Enquirymaintenance.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                   
    EM_ddlTitle.Text = Session["title"].ToString();
    lblEM_FirstName.Text = Session["firstname"].ToString();
    lblEM_LastName.Text = Session["firstname"].ToString();                         
}
```

Comment: And what is your issue with that?

Comment: Where does the data list *get* its data?  The first page shouldn't be passing all of its data to the second page, both pages should simply be getting their data from the same source.

Comment: It seems like OP doesn't understand how SO works... OP has used answers twice to comment out others' answers...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use one of the following approaches:

1. Store changes from page A to the data source (i.e. your database), then redirect to page B and give the *object identifier* as a second page query string parameter, and finally load the target object again. For example:

```
// This is your source page
Response.Redirect("EnquiryMaintenance.aspx?objectId=" + someObjectId);

// This is your target page
string objectId = Request.QueryString["objectId"];
```

2. Store the entire object in memory, either *as is* or in a serialization format like JSON, and access the whole object from the second page. **This is bad idea, because a Web site is a multi-threaded, multi-user client-server application and this approach will eat your server RAM if there're too many user sessions opened**. You might also serialize the object to the store (again, for example the database), but why you would store a phantom object if you can get the right one (see approach 1)??

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach, since you already use datasources, is to pass the key of the selected field as querystring (or as a post request if it should be hidden) and on the other page use the same datasource with the exclusion of the filter via parameter.

This way, if there are future changes to the structure, nothing should be changed (unless the datasource is not taking all values, then the field should be added there).

Don't forget to validate the parameter at Enquirymaintenance.aspx!

Comment: Thanks Sharon.. u mean I don't need to use a Session in this case?

Comment: @Ashraf No, you do not. The SqlDataSource object can set a query parameter from the querystring. Basically it means there needs to be no server code written by you.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the first approach:

I have created new sqldatasource to pass the id(newid) as following:

Emailenquiry.aspx

```
  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_PatientDetails_PD]LEFT JOIN [tbl_MakeAppointment_MA] ON [tbl_PatientDetails_PD].[PD_ID] = [tbl_MakeAppointment_MA].[MA_PD_ID]  LEFT JOIN [tbl_ChangeAppointment_CHA] ON [tbl_PatientDetails_PD].[PD_ID] = [tbl_ChangeAppointment_CHA].[CHA_PD_ID] LEFT JOIN [tbl_CancelAppointment_CA] ON [tbl_PatientDetails_PD].[PD_ID] = [tbl_CancelAppointment_CA].[CA_PD_ID] WHERE ([PD_ID] = @PD_ID)">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="lblEM_ID" Name="PD_ID" PropertyName="Text" 
                        Type="Int32" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

lblEM_ID is set to invisible:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblEM_ID" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```

Emailenquiry.aspx.cs

```
 protected void btnPromote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Response.Redirect("EnquiryMaintenance.aspx?newid=" + lblEM_ID.Text);

        }
```

Enquirymaintenance.aspx.cs

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                string objectId = Request.QueryString["newid"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To: Soner Gönül

What I am trying to do is to pass all values to enquirymaintenance.aspx page. I need to promote the enquiry (data) that I am receiving from emailenquiry.aspx and add another data to database. I tested my code with the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //  lblEM_Title.Text = Session["Title"].ToString();
        if (Session["firstname"] != null)
        {
            EM_ddlTitle.Text = Session["title"].ToString();
            lblEM_FirstName.Text = Session["firstname"].ToString();
            lblEM_LastName.Text = Session["firstname"].ToString();                

        }
        else {
            Label2.Text = "ERROR";
        }
```

}

I tried to pass the "firstname" but I am getting ERROR which means that the data is not passed from emailenquiry.aspx page.

To: Matías Fidemraizer

I tried this method.. because I need to create a new id for every new enquiry.. but it doesn't work:

in Emailenquiry.aspx.cs

```
Response.Redirect("EnquiryMaintenance.aspx?newid=" + lblEM_ID.Text);
```

in Emailenquiry.aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="lblEM_ID" runat="server" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
```